# Where to call AsyncStorage.getItem( ) function to load saved data in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have saved one data inside one class of my react-native project. With saving data I start a new screen. In that screen I am retrieving that saved data. For that purpose, I call **AsyncStorage.getItem('token')** function inside the render function.

Here is the code for that class-

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import {Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';
import CustomHeader from './CustomHeader';

 class NoteMeHome extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text:'',
    storedValue:'',
    getValue: ''
  };

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: "Home",
    headerLeft: <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{paddingLeft:10}}
    onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}/>,

    drawerIcon: 

    <Image source={require('../assets/icon.png')}
            style={styles.icon}
    />
  })

  render() {
    const {storedValue} = this.state;

    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(value =>
      //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
      this.setState({ getValue: value })
      //Setting the value in Text 
    );

    return(
      <Container>
        <CustomHeader
          title="Home"
          drawerOpen={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        />
        <Content contentContainerStyle={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', 
        justifyContent:'center', padding:10}}>
        <Button full onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
          <Text style={{color:'white'}}>{storedValue}</Text>
        </Button>
        <Text>{this.state.getValue}</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon:{
    height: 24,
    width: 24
  }
})
export default NoteMeHome;
```

After that, while running the project, in the above mentioned class, when I click any of my drawer items to go to another screen, it shows the following error in the console-

> wanrning: can't call setState(or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is no-op, but it  indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asyncshronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

I guess something goes wrong with **AsyncStorage.getItem('token')** function calling because if I remove the function it doesn't show any warning.

So, it would be very nice if someone helps me to know where should I call the following code-

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(value =>
  //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
  this.setState({ getValue: value })
  //Setting the value in Text 
);
```

to remove the warning ?

Comment: I think you have more of an issue of React philosophy. You should try to use a hook to set the state or even better, in my opinion : place your "AsyncStorage" call in the componentDidUpdate() function.
The issue that the last rendering somehow is triggered, the component is unmounted, but your async call initiated in the last rendering continue while your component is unmounted.

Comment: Will you please elaborate your description with code because I am not getting it properly. I called the AsyncStorage outside the render function inside componentDidUpdate()  function. But this time it is not retrieving the value.

Answer (score 1):

Asif,

Here is what I had in mind :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import {Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';
import CustomHeader from './CustomHeader';

 class NoteMeHome extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    text:'',
    storedValue:'',
    getValue: ''
  };

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: "Home",
    headerLeft: <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{paddingLeft:10}}
    onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}/>,

    drawerIcon: 

    <Image source={require('../assets/icon.png')}
            style={styles.icon}
    />
  });
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    this.setState({ getValue: token });
  }

  render() {
    const {storedValue, getValue} = this.state;
    return(
      <Container>
        <CustomHeader
          title="Home"
          drawerOpen={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
        />
        <Content contentContainerStyle={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', 
        justifyContent:'center', padding:10}}>
        <Button full onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
          <Text style={{color:'white'}}>{storedValue}</Text>
        </Button>
        <Text>{getValue}</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon:{
    height: 24,
    width: 24
  }
})
export default NoteMeHome;
```

I don't know if in your case you should actually try to handle the update of the component since you don't have any props.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should use `componentDidMount` for anything that you want to do in the beginning of a screen. To use `AsyncStorage` remember that is an `asynchronous` function so you have to wait for the function to complete so you can get the value.

For more information about react native's components please see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

For more information about 'waiting' for AsyncStorage using `async` please see [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) examples

Answer (score 0):

In react component `render()` should always remain pure. One should never set state in render function, it a very bad pracice, in a simple component it might work fine. It only works because of the asynchronicity.

You should use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to fetch data from local storage.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    this.setState({ getValue: token });
}
```